# Firebase admin SDK - cloud (push) messages not delivered

Tags: python, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have this code to send push notifications to Android device.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, messaging


cred = credentials.Certificate('credentials.json') 
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
 

# Create a message to send
message = messaging.Message(
    data={
        'title': 'Hello',
        'body': 'This is a test notification'
    },
    token='<...token...>'
)

# Send the message
response = messaging.send(message)
  
print(response)
```

In my response I got:

```
projects/<projectId>/messages/0:<someId>
```

Based on the response, it seems that message was send. However, device receive no message at all.
If I send the message manually from firebase console to the same device token, message is delivered correctly (so device token should be correct).

Credentials file was generated in firebase console at `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/<projectId>/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk`

Any ideas, what can be wrong?